# How to run multiples docker container when run docker-compose up ( gitlab-ci)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, containers, gitlab-ci

I need to deploy a new container each time that i do "docker-compose up" because the container will run a SQL SERVER database in a Gitlab pipeline for each merge request that will be created in the repository.

Is there a flag that should be passed to do this? I know the --force-recreate, but it recreate the SAME container. I neeed to every time to the command docker-compose up been called to create another container with the same configurations.

There is the --scale SERVICE=NUM, but it is not what i need. Why? because when i scale i can not control which host port docker will grab and use.

how do i intend to do this? By a environment variable. Look:

docker-compose file

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    container_name: ${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "${CI_PIPELINE_ID}:1433"
```

my gitlab-ci:

```
stages:
  - database_deploy
  - build_and_test
  - database_stop

database_deploy:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: database_deploy
  services:
    - name: docker
  script:
    - apk add py-pip
    - pip install docker-compose==1.8.0
    - cd ./docker; docker-compose up -d; docker ps

build_and_test:
  image: maven:latest
  stage: build_and_test
  script:
    - mvn test -Dquarkus.test.profile=homolog
    - mvn checkstyle:check
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target

database_stop: &database_stop
  image: docker:latest
  stage: database_stop
  services:
    - name: docker
  script:
    - docker stop $CI_PIPELINE_ID
    - docker rm -f $CI_PIPELINE_ID
    - docker ps


cleanup_deployment_failure:
  needs: ["build_and_test"]
  when: on_failure
  <<: *database_stop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker-compose groups your services in "projects". By default, the project name is the name of the directory that contains your `docker-compose.yml` file. When you run `docker up`, `docker-compose` will create any containers in the project that don't already exist.

Since you want `docker-compose up` to create new containers every time -- with different configurations -- you need to tell `docker-compose` that it's running in a different project each time. You can do this with the `--project-name` (`-p`) flag.

For example, let's say I have this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: "alpinelinux/darkhttpd"
    ports:
      - "${HOSTPORT}:8080"
```

I can bring up multiple instances of this stack by setting `HOSTPORT` and specifying a project name for each invocation of `docker-compsoe`:

```
$ HOSTPORT=8081 docker-compose -p project1 up -d
$ HOSTPORT=8082 docker-compose -p project2 up -d
```

After running those two commands, we see:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
825ea98cca55   alpinelinux/darkhttpd   "darkhttpd /var/www/…"   4 seconds ago   Up 3 seconds   0.0.0.0:8082->8080/tcp, :::8082->8080/tcp   project2_web_1
776c12d38bbb   alpinelinux/darkhttpd   "darkhttpd /var/www/…"   9 seconds ago   Up 8 seconds   0.0.0.0:8081->8080/tcp, :::8081->8080/tcp   project1_web_1
```

And I think that's exactly what you're looking for.

Note that with this configuration, you will need to specify the project name and a value for `HOSTPORT` every time you run `docker-compose`.

---

You can also set the project name using the [`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) environment variable. This means you can actually organize things using environment files.

We can reproduce the above behavior by creating `project1.env` with:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=project1
HOSTPORT=8081
```

And `project2.env` with:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=project2
HOSTPORT=8082
```

And then running:

```
$ docker-compose --env-file project1.env up -d
$ docker-compose --env-file project2.env up -d
```

As before, you'll need to provide `--env-file` every time you run `docker-compose`.

Comment: Nice, but now i am having some trouble runnig the first command thad you have passed me. Here is a print: https://pasteboard.co/Kg2F3WW.png 

It is saying that "HOSTPORT is not recognized as a intern or external command..."

What do you think that i can do to solve it?

Comment: Those commands assume a standard Unix-style shell. It looks like you're running this on Windows, so...do whatever is standard in Windows for setting an environment variable on the command line. Or just jump to option 2, and use `.env` files.

Comment: this solved my problem. Thanks. The problem was with the flag "-d". I need to understand to where should i pass it in the command line.